# Getting the Green Bullet from the exampleblock in Boadilla Template

Tags: beamer

I am using the Boadilla template with whale color theme. I noticed that the bullets for the itemized block is blue, but if the itemized block is inside an exampleblock, the bullet color turns green.

[image]

I want to get the green bullet and bullet mixed in a plain frame. Can I do that?

Minimum working example is given below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
}

\title[Short title]{Main Topic }
\author{John Smith}
\institute[UCLA]
{
University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{john@smith.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item One Blue Bullet
\item Two Blue Bullet. But want it green color.

\end{itemize}

\begin{exampleblock}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Green Bullet
\item Second Green Bullet
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour of the itemize item with `\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=green!60!black}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}

\begin{document}



    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            {\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=green!60!black}\item One Blue Bullet}
            \item Two Blue Bullet. But want it green color.

        \end{itemize}

        \begin{exampleblock}{Test}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Green Bullet
                \item Second Green Bullet
            \end{itemize}
        \end{exampleblock}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]